# ORM Domain object ACL in JPA

Tags: java, security, jpa, acl

Does anyone know ACL solutions for JPA. I need to set directly permissions on my  entity objects. I have found [jpasecurity](http://jpasecurity.sourceforge.net/index.html) but maybe there are another frameworks?

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 0):

jpasecurity is the only framework as far as I know unless you have found any others since the post?